# sorting on date field with Range filter

Tags: elasticsearch

everyone i am using Es2.0 Version. I want to sort my LogDate Field on range based on date type.

Below is my mapping:

```
       PUT test/_mapping/device
  {
 "device" : {
    "_routing": {"required": true},
    "properties" : {
       "activityId" : {"type" : "long", "store" : true },
       "userId":{"type":"long","store":true},
       "calories":{"type":"float","store":true},
       "description":{"type":"string","store":true},
       "distance":{"type":"float","store":true},
       "duration":{"type":"long","store":true},
       "startTime":{"type": "date","format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"},
       "endTime":{"type": "date","format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"},
      "steps":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "offset":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "lightSleep":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "deepSleep":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "almostAwake":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "s1":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "s2":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "s3":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "s4":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "s5":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "s6":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "s7":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "s8":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "year":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "month":{"type":"long","store":true},
      "activityType":{"type":"string","store":true},
     "logDate":{"type": "date","format" : "yyyy-MM-dd",
     "index":    "not_analyzed"},
    "createdTime":{"type": "date","format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}
   }
   }
   }
```

and my query is that i want to sort LogDate field on given range of dates.

```
    GET test/device/_search
    {   
     "size": 500, 
     "sort": [
    {
      "logDate": {
         "order": "asc"
      }
   }
     ], 
   "fields": [
   "logDate"
     ],
   "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
           {
               "match": {
                  "userId": "305"
               }
           },{
               "range": {

                       "logDate": 
                                {
                                    "from": "2016-01-25",
                                    "to":"2016-01-31"

                                }
               }
                }
        ]
       }
      }
      }
```

It is not showing me as expected output.It showing me 25-01 to 28-02 i.e,It is not analyzinf month.
Please guys help me out am struck on ti since last night.Thanku very much.

Answer (score 0):

According to Elasticsearch 2.0 [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-range-query.html), `range` query works with `lte`, `lt`, `gt` and `gte` respectively, not **from** and **to**. So changing your range query should fix your problem:

```
"range": {
    "logDate": 
        {
           "gte": "2016-01-25",
           "lte": "2016-01-31"
        }
}
```

Also, have you tried using a simple `and` query rather than the `bool`? 
From your description you're not concerned with the `_score` returned by ES.

Elasticsearch [quer vs filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_queries_and_filters.html) points out when `query` and `filter` should be used.
Have you tried using a `filtered` query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_combining_queries_with_filters.html)?

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query":  { "match": { "userId": "305" }},
            "filter": { 
               "range": { 
                   "logDate": {
                       "gte": "2016-01-25", 
                       "lte": "2016-01-31"
                   } 
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had another look over your query & updated the answer - looks like `filtered` query might be better for what you're trying to achieve. Since ES doesn't have **from** and **to** as options for `range` query/filter, you should stick with `lte` and `gte`.

Comment: filtered query has been deprecated https://www.elastic.co/blog/better-query-execution-coming-elasticsearch-2-0

Comment: I was not aware of that. Then did you try surrounding your `range` with `filter`, like in the example in that blog post and move it outside the `must`? `“filter”: { "range": { "gte": "2016-01-25", "lte": "2016-01-31" } }`